# Creating a dictionary for specific positions of characters in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, pygame

I'm trying to search a file for an instance of #, M,K, O, D and for each instance, return {position(tuple), instance type(#, M,K, O, D)} in a dictionary. I have written a function to find the coordinates of an instance in a file, however I am not sure how to add and update a whole dictionary with this
information. This is what I have so far:

```
def init_game_information(dungeon_name="game1.txt"):
        self._dungeon=load_game(dungeon_name)
        game_dict={}
        with open("game1.txt", "r") as file:
            for line in file:
                for row, line in enumerate(self._dungeon):
                    for col, char in enumerate(line):
                        if WALL in line:
                            x=WALL
                            y=get_positions(self, WALL)
                            dict_WALL={y,x}
                        game_dict.update(dict_WALL)
                        if KEY in line:
                            x=KEY
                            y=get_positions(self, KEY)
                            KEY={y,x}
                        game_dict.update(dict_KEY)
                        if DOOR in line:
                            x=DOOR
                            y=get_positions(self, DOOR)
                            dict_DOOR={y,x}
                        game_dict.update(dict_DOOR)
                        if MOVE_INCREASE in line:
                            x=MOVE_INCREASE
                            y=get_positions(self, MOVE_INCREASE)
                            dict_MOVE={y,x}
                        game_dict.update(dict_MOVE)
                
            
def get_positions(self, entity):
    """ Returns a list of tuples containing all positions of a given Entity
         type.

    Parameters:
        entity (str): the id of an entity.

    Returns:
        )list<tuple<int, int>>): Returns a list of tuples representing the 
        positions of a given entity id.
    """
    positions = []
    for row, line in enumerate(self._dungeon):
        for col, char in enumerate(line):
            if char == entity:
                positions.append((row,col))

    return positions
```

and this is an example of the game file/ what should be returned:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have classes for `Wal`, `Door`, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a value to a key in a dictionary by `dictionary[key] = value`. Define a key by the `row` and `col` and associate it to the dictionary:

```py
keys = [WALL, KEY, DOOR, MOVE_INCREASE]
game_dict = {}
with open("game1.txt", "r") as file:
    for row, line in enumerate(file):
        for col, char in enumerate(line):

            if char in keys:
                game_dict[(row, col)] = char
```

---

If you have classes for the object (`Wall`, `Key`, ...), then you can do something like:

```py
class_dict = { WALL : Wall, KEY : Key, DOOR : Door, MOVE_INCREASE: MoveIncrease}

game_dict = {}
with open("game1.txt", "r") as file:
    for row, line in enumerate(file):
        for col, char in enumerate(line):

            if char in class_dict:
                game_dict[(row, col)] = class_dict[char](char)

print(game_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway for the function to skip an instance where there is an empty space/ nothing and not add anything to the dictionary, as the error I am running into is "AssertionError: None is not an instance of <class 'dict'>"

Comment: @kit01 I'm confused. Where do you get this error. In general you have just to test `if key != None:`. But I don't know where  you get this error and what actually is you key.